# Initializing hidden Slick.js carousel, items showing with width 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to initialize `slick` on a modal which **is initially hidden**.

In WordPress, I have a `custom post type` called `experiences`. I have `ACF` fields and trying to extract those field items and show it in a modal popup. So, the way the modal works is:

- On the `experiences` listing page, user clicks on "Learn more". Learn more is a trigger to open the modal.
- [On button click, it will get data from those ACF fields for that post]
- The markup with the extracted fields is then appended to the global modal which is found in the footer.

The container which houses the markup that is appended is `#expHTML`. This element is hidden and its inner HTML is appended to the `#global-modal`.

So, when I'm trying to display the images assigned to an `experience` post, the `img`s where `slick` is initiliazed is showing with `width: 0px`.

I have tried to reinit slick on button click, but it doesn't work. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('.slick').slick('unslick').slick('reinit').slick();

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Neither of them work and the `img`s are still showing `width:0`

Demo:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).on("click", '.trigger', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var modalID = '#global-modal';
    $('.modal').removeClass('modal--open');

    $(modalID).fadeIn(200,function(){
      $(this).addClass('modal--open');
    });

    var experience_html = $("#expHTML").html();
    $(modalID).html(experience_html);
    return false;

    $('.slick').slick('unslick').slick('reinit').slick();

  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}

a{
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div id="expHTML" class="hidden">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="slick">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200X200/802380/fff.png&text=IMAGE+1"/>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200X200/374cbf/ffffff.png&text=IMAGE+2"/>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200X200/6ebd7e/ffffff.png&text=IMAGE+3"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="trigger">Click me</a>

<!-- Modal  popup-->
<div class="modal" id="global-modal">
  <div class="modal__inner">
    <a class="modal__close"></a>
    <div class="modal__box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run your snippet, I get an error in the Slick script.  I'm thinking that Script might be dependent on JQuery, so you might want to have JQuery defined before Slick and see if that gets yo anywhere.

Comment: I reversed the two so that the example runs.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are returning from your onclick function before you attempt to reset your slideshow, which means that the reset code will never be executed.

```
$(document).on("click", '.trigger', function(e) {

  ...

  return false;

  $('.slick').slick('unslick').slick('reinit').slick();
});
```

Also, you should be able to clear up the image width issue by refreshing your slideshow after you reveal your modal contents, instead of trying to "unslick" and "reinit":

```
$('.slick').slick("refresh");
```

More information about the hidden slideshow issue: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/235

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and got an `Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined` error (here's a fiddle showing my exact JS: https://jsfiddle.net/9ebfcvaj/2/)

I also tried to init slick after the modal is open, but get an `Cannot read property 'add' of null` error (here's another fiddle with that JS: https://jsfiddle.net/be12d0rt/)

I have also seen that issue on GitHub, the suggested solutions there didn't work for me (Aerials92's answer also gave me a `Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined` error